# TinyMCE image picker

Tags: javascript, tinymce, blob

Here's the code I use :

```
 tinymce.init({
      selector: 'textarea',
      plugins: 'image code',
      toolbar: 'undo redo | link image | code',
      
      image_title: true,
      
      automatic_uploads: true,
        picker_types: 'image',

      file_picker_callback: function (cb, value, meta) {
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
        input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');



        input.onchange = function () {
          var file = this.files[0];

          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function () {

            var id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
            var blobCache =  tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
            var base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];
            var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, base64);
            blobCache.add(blobInfo);

            cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
          };
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        };

        input.click();
      },
      content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }'
    });
```

This code creates a blob, but I don't want it to.
Let me explain:
When I select an image (images/test/picture.png), it becomes blob:https://project/78126513-4714-8e15-7c23-a3cc210c8dc9.
I'd like to know if it's possible to take the path and avoid the blob? To have images/test/picture.png in the database instead of blob:https://project/78126513-4714-8e15-7c23-a3cc210c8dc9.

Thanks a lot!